# Adding espresso-contrib to androidTestImplementation creates dependancy / constraint errors

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am following an older tutorial on PluralSight: [Enhancing the Android Application Experience](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/android-enhancing-application-experience). Since I am using a newer version of the IDE I have been running into some issues. Most I can fix here at SO but I am stuck and have not enough experience beyond what I know.

In setting up some unit tests I had to add `androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'` to the gradle file. The instructor eluded to this creating some issues since

> The espresso-contrib library is actually relying on different versions of certain classes than we are using in our application. Cause remember that gradle takes care of resolving down chain dependencies

The errors experience in the module were not the ones I was getting below. They were fixed by adding explicit calls to the libraries in the TestCompile. Me doing the same thing doesn't address the problem.

```
Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   Constraint path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 24.2.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.2.1
   Dependency path 'NoteKeeper:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

My app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jwhh.jim.notekeeper"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

---

I looked around for solutions here but didn't find anything that fit.

[Resources error when I add espresso-contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55097681/resources-error-when-i-add-espresso-contrib) talked about changing the SDK version. Everything I have done was to match 24 so I don't think changing that will make things better. Perhaps I am using the wrong espresso builds?

[Espresso test aren't running after adding espresso-contrib library in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275299/espresso-test-arent-running-after-adding-espresso-contrib-library-in-gradle) suggests that I need to add some exclusions which I tried as follows with no obvious difference. Also, not entirely sure what this is suppose to do.

```
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    })
```

I poked around the [Espresso Setup](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup) but got lost and found no caveats when it came to `espresso-contrib`

---

At the advice of a user I removed the extra dependencies from `androidTestImplementation` but I still got errors

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
}
```

> `Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' that satisfies the version constraints:...`

Comment: If this ends up being a dupe I am hoping for an explanation and not just a code snippet without context. Still green at this and don't want to code bite and run away

Comment: So after playing more I tried to lower the library version of `espresso-contrib` and `espresso-core`. So my test attempts to run but files since methods are missing. How do I get the right espresso version to match my SDK?

Comment: I tried 3.0.1, 3.0.0 and 2.2.2. The latter compiles but failed to execute my function. Likely because its old

Comment: Why don't you try `AndroidX` artifact instead?

Comment: @JeelVankhede I will have to look up what that means. I am doing what I am doing as I am following a guided tutorial online. So perhaps that is a better way that will be revealed to me later.

Comment: All I want to say is try to **Migrate to AndroidX** and check if issue resolves as it's latest dependencies for support libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the error is telling you that different part of your code (main code and Android test code) depend on different versions of the Support Library, in this case, 24.2.1 and 27.1.1.

**What does it mean?**

Let's say that you have some class `InternalImportantThing`. And your code depends on v1 of that class. And then you add some library (`espresso-contrib` in your case) that depends on v2 of that class.

The problem is that both of the classes have the same, let's say, "path". E.g. `com.myapp.InternalImportantThing`. And you can't have both of them in the same app, as the Classloader will get crazy in this case: "Which class to take: `com.myapp.InternalImportantThing` or `com.myapp.InternalImportantThing`?" (And yes, they are the same - that's the problem).

That's why you have to resolve the conflict. There are different ways to do it, we'll discuss it later.

**What happens after resolution?**

It depends. If v1 and v2 have the same public API and differ only in implementation, everything may work well. Or may not, if the methods produce different results for the same inputs. But if v2 lacks some of the apis of v1 and v1 doesn't have smth from v2 - you are in trouble. Because you will need to choose one and either your app or the dependent lib may loose something on what they relied upon.

**Couple of links about it**

[Gradle conflicts resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421108/how-does-gradle-choose-between-more-than-1-versions-of-the-same-library-in-a-gra/47421769#47421769)

[Troubleshoot dependencies resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting_dependency_resolution.html)

The latter one is pretty long, in your case, you can force your main app to use the latest versions of support libs (like `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`). That may require you to update your `compileSdk` / `targetSdk` as well, please, pay attention on warnings and errors.

You can find the latest versions [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) or use helpers from Android Studio.

The only tip is try not to import anything from AndroidX packages as you can't have both AndroidX and non-AndroidX depencencies. It's easy to find them: they start with `androidx`, you can find examples [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: I will certainly read up on what I can. The tutorial acknowledges this happens and mitigates it be adding specific dependencies in the androidTestImplementation and/or exclusions. Difference for me is I am using a newer version of AndroidStudio but that should not have much to do with it. Likely I will just compile with a greater SDK version just to keep going. Thanks again.

Comment: An alternative is to downgrade Espresso dependencies. Can you try with 2.2.2? com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2 or even 2.1, com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.1 And the same for espresso-core

Comment: I had that in a comment. I get past the errors if I downgrade to espresso 2.2.2 but the methods I am using don't exist there so I get an error for this `onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());`

Comment: According to this post, Espresso 2.2.2 should have Drawer Actions in it. Can you try to re-import it?  https://developersjournal.in/steps-to-setup-espresso-for-android-apps/

Comment: Or can you publish your test app (or part of it) to a github? Cause it looks like a project config specific issue.

Comment: I think I got it. I just needed to add some more excludes to `espresso-contrib`: 'appcompat-v7', 'design', 'support-compat', 'recyclerview-v7', 'support-core-utils'. After that the test works as designed. I guess I just had to keep reading the debug to know I had not added enough. Now I can continue with the training. So either way to helped me get to the answer. Thanks for your time in this busy tag

Comment: Cool, have a good one! Will appreciate if you accept the answer. Remote debugging is not a straightforward thing :)